# QR Code AddressBook

Tags: qr-code

I'm planning to use QR Code AddressBook on my project currently I'm using 3 0f 9 Barcode. I'm capturing Name, and Account number. but the barcode it's quite long.

I found out the QrCode Address book can capture a long characters including address website phone number, website and etc.

Does the QRCodes Address book works the same way with 3of9. from plain text just change the fonts it will convert to barcode.

If not what is the process to converting clear text to qrCode address.

Thanks in advance,

Ryl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't work like that.

You can use a third-party-library like zxing

https://github.com/zxing/zxing

or use this library and tools or watch at the provided sourecode.